# Hiding URL Parameters from Controller to View: MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Say I have a website with a wide variety of different pages, each tailored for an individual user and accessible only by that user. When a user accesses a page, the URL for that page will be `UserStuff/Pages/11`, where `11` is the page's ID. Right now, because users can have multiple pages, I am using an ActionLink element to direct the user to their selected page, like so:

```
// In Index.cshtml
// ...
@Html.ActionLink("View Page", "Pages", new { id = page.ID }, new { @class=...})
```

The controller intercepts the given id:

```
public ActionResult Pages(int id) 
{
    // ...
    Page page = db.Pages.Find(id);
    return View(page);
}
```

This works well and delivers exactly how I want the application to behave. However, I wish for the ID to be hidden in the URL. How do I pass information from the View to the controller via a parameter without having it exposed in the URL? Say that I don't want the Page's ID visible in the URL, how can I link to a different Action that takes the given parameter?

I believe that keeping the request a GET request is important due to other actions redirecting to the resulting page. Wrapping it in a form/POST request would make said actions unable to access the information without having to go through the same process as the original user, which is not something that I want in this implementation.

Comment: You can't 'hide' the url (and in any case a user can type what ever they want in the address bar). If you don't pass the value to the controller, then the controller will never get it. If you don't want users to access a resource with a particular ID, then perform the check in the controller

Comment: Sure, the user can always type whatever they want in the URL and my Action method performs authentication to prevent viewing others' pages. That said, I was just wondering whether or not I could cut off the `/{id}` portion of the URL purely for display purposes.

Comment: If you want to pass the ID to the controller, then the url must include the value of the ID

Comment: Makes sense. If I were to use a POST request instead of a GET request in this particular example, would that be considered bad practice given that I only want to retrieve information?

Comment: A POST method is for changing data, so it should be a GET, but what is the issue with displaying the ID in the url?